# List item won't change height in response to large text from accessibility being turned on

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, accessibility

I'm currently working in React Native and I'm trying to make my list item components accessible to people with poor vision and might need bigger text, because of this I've ran into some issues with the text clipping or not showing entirely. What I'm trying to do is pretty straightforward, if the user turns on large text in accessibility then my event listener will pick up on it and using that information will determine the height of my list component when rendering. Unfortunately, it seems as though my app can never detect when the accessibility is on because in the console I get a lot of `false` and default height of 50 (when no large text is active). I'll attach some screenshots and then some code.

This is what my list view looks with large text, as you can see the text has gotten bigger but my individual list items aren't sizing correctly to fit the bigger text (should be 150, but still at 50).

[image: List items don't size correctly]

This is what I get in the console..

[image: console output]

Now here are some bits of code. Note, I omitted some code for brevity.

```
class NodeListItem extends PureComponent {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            largeTextEnabled: undefined,
        };
        this.itemPressed = this.itemPressed.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AccessibilityInfo.addEventListener(
          'change',
          this._handleAccessibilityToggled
        );
        AccessibilityInfo.fetch().done((isEnabled) => {
            console.log(`Is enabled didMount: ${isEnabled}`);
            this.setState({
                largeTextEnabled: isEnabled,
            });
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        AccessibilityInfo.removeEventListener(
          'change',
          this._handleAccessibilityToggled
        );
    }

    _handleAccessibilityToggled = (isEnabled) => {
        this.setState({
            largeTextEnabled: isEnabled,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { displayName } = this.props.item;
        const adjustForAccessibility = this.state.largeTextEnabled ? 150 : 50
        console.log(`Here is height: ${adjustForAccessibility} and it is: ${this.state.largeTextEnabled}`);
        console.log(`Height ${this.state.largeTextEnabled ? 150 : 50}`);
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1, height: this.state.largeTextEnabled ? 150 : 50 }} onPress={this.itemPressed}>
                <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
                    <Text style={CommonStyles.textDefaultBlackMedium} textAlign={'left'} allowFontScaling={true} numberOfLines={3} >{displayName}</Text>
                    {this.renderArrow()}
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

I took inspiration from these 2 links, [first](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo) and [second](https://code.fb.com/android/making-react-native-apps-accessible/). Essentially the idea is my app listens for change in accessibility and then updates the state with a boolean, then when rendering my component reads the value and adjusts height accordingly. Any idea why my list item components are not updating their size from 50 to 150 after turning accessibility on? I only ever see undefined or false in the console. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Resolved in the comments, issue was that the setting being altered was not part of the AccessibilityInfo API.

After a quick search I came across this issue which looks like the solution you are after:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14725

No need to jump too deep into native code, you can almost always be certain someones already written it :P Especially with the recent focus on accessibility.

---

A Toggle function, when used with state should always reference the previous state and simple invert the boolean.

I'm not sure where your accessibility button is, but essentially your toggle function should look more like this:

```
_handleAccessibilityToggled = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                largeTextEnabled: !prevState.largeTextEnabled,
            }            
        });
    };
```

This way every click will flick the largeTextEnabled to the opposite state, I would also suggest removing event listeners for the button click and holding the state in a parent of both components if possible.

The main issue is that onChange you aren't actually passing `isEnabled` to the toggle function hence why it is always undefined or false.

Comment: This is good information but when large text is enabled from the accessibility settings I have to leave the app and go to settings and change from there, then go back into the app. I followed your advice and it just seems like the accessibility info api just isn't updating correctly, in fact I put a console.log in the _handleAccessibilityToggled method and I never see it print in the console, any other ideas?

Comment: Oh jeeze you are leaving the app for this, that makes it a little bit harder without a lot more context XD

If you are leaving the scope of your app to toggle the button, than the entire app will be unmounted rendering your listeners pointless, and the only thing that will be triggered is the fetch() on mount which i'm assuming is returning undefined.

You are almost moving into "A whole new question" territory here, I can't really help you without the details

Comment: Oh I see, so to be more clear, when the user decides they want bigger text they will navigate to their settings > accessibility > large text (on iOS for example) . After turning on large text they open the app back up from being in the background and what should happen is the app should detect that large text from settings has been toggled on and allow for font scaling. Since you mentioned the app unmounting is there a way to keep the event listeners intact even when the app goes into the background? Let me know if there's more confusion on your end.

Comment: Yeah I understand now, I think I may have been leading you astray after double checking the docs your code is right.

Have you tried opening the app cleanly with Accessibility already toggled to true?

To test if the fetch() on mount works as expected

Comment: I have, regardless of whether I have the large text is turned on or off the logs always return false for some reason. My theory is the 'AccessibilityInfo' api is just outdated because I implemented it exactly like the docs said and it fails to return a true when large text is on, so I'm not entirely sure what else to try at the moment. Here is some expo code, you can probably try running on your device, for me it always returned 'disabled' even if large text was on. Here's the example: https://snack.expo.io/SJXu6JmYX

Comment: What is the setting you are changing? Sorry for the delayed response, AccessibilityInfo is enabled when a screen reader is active (The docs state this) so i'm wondering if you are looking at the right setting?

Comment: That was my mistake, for some reason I thought that the screen reader being active included the large text setting in accessibility (for iOS). If that is the case then the code above won't work because it's not listening for the setting I thought it would be. At this point I'm thinking of just writing native code to handle listening for the setting I'm looking for, I think that might be my only way.

Comment: Updated the Answer with an edit and a link for you :P please give a boy an updoot so everyone knows it's resolved! :)